# no puedo incluir mi icono dentro de mi input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No logro que mi icono se guarde dentro del input no sé si será en las propiedades

Suscripcion a boletines

Suscribete a nuestras noticias

Correo:

Celular

Suscribir

**codigo ccs**

.

```
form-control {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-control {
  padding-left: 30px!important;
}

.header {
    color: #36A0FF;
    font-size: 27px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bigicon {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #36A0FF;
}
```

tambien queria saber si alguien me puede decir como hacer para centrar y colocar mi formulario de una tamaño especifico?

Comment: Deberías compartir un poco mas el código para saber que has hecho y poder ayudarte

Comment: Añade más código

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás forzando un poquito las cosas usando los estilos personalizados. Bootstrap te da básicamente todo lo que pudieras necesitar para lograr un diseño limpio y bien organizado.

Lamentablemente no has agregado suficiente código para saber exactamente lo que estás haciendo. Por lo tanto, y de acuerdo al código que has subido, esta sería una forma de obtener un resultado (espero que sea el deseado) que hará ver tu diseño bastante bien.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear un campo tipo `input` que contenga un ícono de usuario. Además se desea que el campo se encuentre centrado en el contenedor.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para obtener el resultado deseado usaremos el framework de [Bootstrap v.4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/), y el icono SVG lo obtendremos del framwork [Font Awesome v5.7](https://fontawesome.com/).

Usaremos los siguientes estilos de Bootstrap:

1. container-fluid
2. form-group
3. row
4. justify-content-center
5. mt-4
6. col-md-4 col-6
7. input-group
8. flex-nowrap
9. input-group-prepend
10. input-group-text
11. form-control

Algo para destacar, en tu código veo que usas las clases `col-md-1 col-md-offset-2` y `col-md-8`, sin embargo están huérfanas, o no has incluido en tu código el contenedor tipo `row`. La documentación de [Bootstrap - Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) establece lo siguiente: (traducción propia)

> - Las **Filas** son empaques o envoltorios para **Columnas**. Cada columna tiene un `padding` horizontal (conocido como `gutter`) para controlar el espacio entre las mismas....
> - En un esquema de rejilla (grid layout), el contenido debe colocarse dentro de columnas, y sólo elementos de columna pueden ser hijos inmediatos de elementos fila.

Dicho esto, debes siempre usar un contenedor tipo `row` para usar los contenedores tipo `col`, los cuales serán siempre los hijos directos del contenedor `row`.

Por último el código que hace que todo funcione es el siguiente, has de notar que no uso ningún estilo `css` distinto del que me proporciona Bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Como puedes apreciar en el código, todo tiene un orden y con las clases de Bootstrap las cosas se ven bastante bien.

Puede leer más en [Bootstrap - Input Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/), para que veas las posibilidades que ofrece.

Espero que esto sea lo que buscabas.